# Issue on loading corrupted excel file with R

Tags: r, corruption, import-from-excel

I'm actually trying to import multiple excel files with R but I encounter a problem when I try to load a corrupt one.

My excel files (.xlsm) are in different folders like this :

Machine 
        -- >years 
                 --> months 
                            --> many excel files 
                                          --> load file --> actions on each file

I use multiple sapply function to make a loop and perform some actions with the file datas. Due to corrupt file, the process stops. 
I tried R functions like file.access() and file_test() but it doesn't help to fix my problem.

What I'm looking for is a function or an embedded shell command which will allow me to know if the actual file is corrupt and then avoid it.

Thanks,
Thomas.

Comment: `?try` could be useful?

Comment: You could also print to the console each file name, so you can track down the offending file

Comment: I already print each file name so i know that the last one before the warning is the corrupted but I have to handle about 6500 files...
I'll try with these function but I don't really understand how they work.

To answer your question nrussell, when I try to open the file with excel in windows, it says me that that the file is unreadable and asks me if I want to repair it. And when I say Yes, it says me that "the workbook can't be opened and repaired by Microsoft Excel because it's corrupted.